# Remapping <Ctrl-?> keys in X11

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I recently started using Colemak layout. Of course, all shortcuts like `<Ctrl-T>` for opening a new tab changed their positions. That's fine, after all, its all mnemonics.

However, there is a problem. I also use Cyrillic layout, and it doesn't know anything about my Latin one. That is, when I press `<Ctrl-Something>` then Something is recognized as a Qwerty key and not a Colemak one.

Is there a way to remap `<Ctrl-?>` to Colemak for other layouts? I checked out `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` but the only thing I see there is the layout config with Shift and AltGr keys pressed.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.